# DLL Method Not Working After Creating Exe Of Project

Tags: java, c#, methods, dll, java-native-interface

I have calling display method from dll file This works when I run my java project . But it stop working after creating of project exe file. My Code is as follow ..

```
static {

    try {
        Bridge.setVerbose(true);
        try {
            Bridge.init();
        } catch (IOException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
        }
         File dll_File = new File("helloworld.j4n.dll");
        Bridge.LoadAndRegisterAssemblyFrom(dll_File);

         helloworld.Hello.display(str)


    } catch (Exception exception) {

          exception.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: helloworld.Hello.display(str) This method is In Jar File @ClrMethod(value = "(LSystem/String;)Z")
    public static native boolean display(String string);

Answer (score 0):

Have you signed the dll? Please sign the dll and then check.

Comment: No I have not signed the dll

Comment: Ok I will check it

Comment: use the link https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/341645/Referenced-assembly-does-not-have-a-strong-name to sign your dll.

Comment: Error Shows Failed to Launch JVM